# GDB find struct address given some fields values

Tags: c, gdb

I am working with ESXi kernel core dump and I would like to lookup some variables. Unfortunately there are no symbols in dump. I was able to narrow down position of my struct to reasonable address range. I can use my binary with symbols, so gdb knows definition of my struct. Is there a way to search this address range for my struct candidates, knowing that certain fields have predefined values?

Comment: Will the gdb ```find``` command do what you need? You can search for specific patterns within memory ranges.

Comment: I managed to get hexdump of my struct. Is there a way to read it in gdb (or some other way, since I have symbol file)?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that; you may just have to search for the specific byte(s) you know are in your struct, adjust the address to account for the size and arrangement of the struct to get its base address, and then have ```gdb``` print it.

Comment: GDB’s `find` command will accept a comma-separated sequence of integers, each of which can be in hex (preceded by `0x`), so your hexdump should be usable with a little bit of editing

Comment: just written a program that loads hex to memory, prints address and cores, worked just fine, thx all